# Find out the user who deployed Azure Data Factory pipeline in ADF v1

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory

We are having a ADF V1 pipeline, which we had paused to avoid data flowing in. Suddenly, we see that it has been deployed in running mode, by some user. How to find out who  had deployed the azure data factory pipeline.

When I see in the azure portal, I only see the deployment time. I don't see the user, who deployed it. I also tried to see the same using azure powershell also. But, not able to find.

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "TestSubscriptionName"

(Get-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline -DataFactoryName "TestDataFactory"       
-ResourceGroupName "TestRG" -Name "TestPipeline").Properties.RuntimeInfo
```

Please let me know, how can I find out the user, who had deployed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The activity log contains all write operations (PUT, POST, DELETE) performed on your resources. It does not include read operations (GET).

Through activity logs, you can determine:

- what operations were taken on the resources in your subscription
- who initiated the operation (although operations initiated by a
  backend service do not return a user as the caller)
- when the operation occurred
- the status of the operation
- the values of other properties that might help you research the
  operation

You can also use the below PowerShell cmdlet to retrieve the log entries.

```
Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceGroup ExampleGroup
```

For more details, refer to [View activity logs to audit actions on resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit).